# WordPress: Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s) not found

Tags: wordpress, video, upload, mp4

I'm trying to add a MP4 video to my media library. It doesn't give any error but when I try to play the video it gives this message inside the video player:

> Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s) not found

The video size is 2MB.

Comment: what is the file size of the video you are trying to use?

Comment: The size of the video is 2mb. There is another useful data for the problem?

Comment: Disable all of your plugins and test to see if your media library is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in WordPress Core about this:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42874#comment:8

An issue is also opened in the mediaelement GH repo:

https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/issues/2390

The actual problem comes from Safari:

`IMPORTANT NOTE for Safari users (Jun 8, 2017)
Since Sierra version, autoplay policies have changed. You may experience an error if you try to execute play programatically or via autoplay attribute with MediaElement, unless muted attribute is specified.`

I've also bumped into this issue, but can only reproduce it in Safari, it works on Chrome and Firefox.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the filename has no spaces, apostrophes, slashes or other non-alphanumeric characters (such as $, % and &). Rename the file before uploading if it does. To preserve readability, it's work for me

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a `.htaccess` file in the `<wp-root>/wp-content` folder of your wordpress installation, this file determines which file the webserver is allowed to make available for download. (You will need access to the server for this, you cannot do this from WordPress itself, I think.)

In my case, this file looked as follows:

```
# Disable access to all file types except the following
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|pdf|docx|rtf|odf|zip|rar)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Which means: only allow downloading files with the listed extentions. Any other file (such as mp4) would result in a `403 - Forbidden` error.

Fix the problem by adding the mp4 to the list of allowed files:

```
...
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|pdf|docx|rtf|odf|zip|rar|mp4)$">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours trying to find a solution i finally have!

I managed to fix the issue by just changing the file name of the MP4. I had the file name as "video_300x250.mp4". by changing it o simply "video_01.mp4" it fixed the issue for me.

I literally spent so long trying to re-install wordpress, mess about with SSL and plenty of other stuff. Trying to google it no one has found any answer. It might be the fact that there are numbers with the letter "x" in it, or some other combination of letters which doesn't work.

I hope this helps for anyone searching for this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I came up with is to change the video's format to **webm** from mp4 that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your video to YouTube then download it and upload the YouTube download to Wordpress and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using H.264 format and reducing the frame rate fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot for this problem.
But I did not get the result.
and one way fix error is to
delete this code

```
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
```

and
The problem was solved